# can i delete array of listView but not update listview?

Tags: java, android-studio

I spent some time to google it, but didn't help.

I have a listview that contains an `ArrayList`.

Can I collect all data in array, show it in listView and delete array, but not update listView - so data will be on screen?

Comment: Please explain more? you want copy array item to listview and show list vew?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: by task i need to put 2 xml files into cache for 5 mins (mb its just keep in memory for 5 mins)  and show it on screen.
now i did it, but when i do array.clear - there are 2 ways:
notifyDataSetChanged and whitescreen or crash programm (if not using notify)

Answer (score 0):

Yes until you scroll the list view to next visible item (or call notify item set change), then `ListView` ask adapter to provide object for example at 5th position and you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or `NullPointerException`. So if you want to avoid that you have to copy your list elements to another ArrayList instance and pass it to your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayListMain.get(position).remove(arrayListChild.get(position));
notifydatasetchange();
```

arrayListMain is which arraylist your are use at setAdapter and arraylistChild is arrayList in your adapter